# How can I save input to a file?

Tags: io, gforth

I use gforth running on linux boxes.

For one of my mini-applications I want to register a formatted text output from a few different user inputs.

Here is the INPUT$ I use:

```
: INPUT$  
  pad swap accept pad swap ;
```

I think this is correct. I tested it this way:

```
cr ." enter something : " 4 INPUT$ CR 
enter something : toto 
 ok
cr ." enter something : " 8 INPUT$ CR 
enter something : titi 
 ok
.S <4> 140296186274576 4 140296186274576 4  ok
```

My file definition:

```
256 Constant max-line
Create line-buffer  max-line 2 + allot
//prepare file for Write permissions :    
s" foo.out" w/o create-file throw Value fd-out
: close-output ( -- )  fd-out close-file throw ;
```

The end goal is to build very small files as:

```
data1;data2;data3
data4;data5;data6
```

where each data is the user input (*`asked 3times to insert text & a second wave of 3 inputs`*)

I did not find documentation about how I can use text inputs to build my file.

How can I call my stack data to copy them to the text file format? (*using type will only echo texts to my terminal*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the Forth `write-file` and `write-line` words, which are documented here: https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/General-files.html

```
write-file ( c-addr u fileid -– ior )

write-line ( c-addr u fileid –- ior )
```

Pass the address and length of your text buffer, and the file ID (`fd-out` in your example) to write text to the file.  The `ior` result will be zero on success.

Comment: Thank you I understand  & interactive mode test is OK. I think now I am able to adapt my code & use it.